# PHP: work with colors directly without imagecolorallocate?

Tags: php, gd

After working with a lot of GD recently (for some fairly large scale projects for work) I had been dealing with RGB codes that I am not so accustomed to.

My co-workers and I had been suffering some what to find a good method to do this without resorting to a makeshift 'hex to rgb' function with arrays for just a simple function.

There must be a way?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623176/php-allocate-color-without-image-resource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am aware `imagecolorallocate()` only returns a hex representation to be used by the other GD functions, as the library is a bit lower level than PHP of course it works with hex values directly, so there raised a need for an intermediate function to assign a colour.

The following should be equivalent:

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor("200", "100");
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$white = 0x00FFFFFF;
$alphagreen = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 0, 255, 0, 64); 
$alphagreen = 0x4000FF00;
```

Comment: Although just note you will be required the `true color` format to use this.