# PHP: Convert hex color from color input to PHP hex number

Tags: php, colors, hex, color-picker

I want to convert my hex color from a color input (example: #FFFFFF) to a PHP hex number format (example: 0xFFFFFF).

i tried to replace the # with 0x by using str_replace but this converted it to a string, I want to keep it a number.

Any solution?

Comment: You can use the number() function of PHP to convert your string into a number.

Comment: [hexdec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php) & [dechex()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php)

Comment: @LajosArpad what number() !!?

Comment: This [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623176/php-allocate-color-without-image-resource/55274609#55274609) will do all sorts of conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this function is what you need?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php

"Returns the decimal equivalent of the hexadecimal number represented by the hex_string argument. hexdec() converts a hexadecimal string to a decimal number.

hexdec() will ignore any non-hexadecimal characters it encounters."

**Some added info:**

dechex() will give you a string containing a hex representation of the number if you need it, but it seems you should be dealing with an integer if it's a number that you need to pass around.

Comment: my question is simple: i want to convert css color representation in hex (for example #FFFFFF) to PHP hex number (for example 0x000000).

Comment: @RafikHaceb I added some context to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this, Found a [function here](http://bavotasan.com/2011/convert-hex-color-to-rgb-using-php/)

```
        function hex2rgb($hex) {
            $hex = str_replace("#", "", $hex);

            if(strlen($hex) == 3) {
                $r = hexdec(substr($hex,0,1).substr($hex,0,1));
                $g = hexdec(substr($hex,1,1).substr($hex,1,1));
                $b = hexdec(substr($hex,2,1).substr($hex,2,1));
            } else {
                $r = hexdec(substr($hex,0,2));
                $g = hexdec(substr($hex,2,2));
                $b = hexdec(substr($hex,4,2));
            }
            $rgb = array($r, $g, $b);
            return implode("", $rgb); // returns the rgb values separated by commas
            //return $rgb; // returns an array with the rgb values
        }
        echo $rgb = hex2rgb("#cc0");
```

Comment: @BeatAlex. Thanks for pointing out, there is an option for both array and number aswell!

Comment: I somehow deleted my comment, was an accident. But I didn't look into it and if there's a number then I apologies!

Comment: @BeatAlex, No issues!

Comment: I didn't ask for RGB representation , i want to convert a css color representation in hex to php hex number:

#FFFFFF to 0xFFFFFF