# Convert RGB to hex color values in PHP

Tags: php

in my code i have

```
$color = rgb(255, 255, 255);
```

i want to convert this into hex color code.Out put like

```
$color = '#ffffff';
```

Comment: gist.github.com/Pushplaybang/5432844 ... Have a look

Comment: This will do it [conversion function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623176/php-allocate-color-without-image-resource/55274609#55274609)

Answer (score 113):

A simple [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) will do.

```
$color = sprintf("#%02x%02x%02x", 13, 0, 255); // #0d00ff
```

To break down the format:

- `#` - the literal character #
- `%` - start of conversion specification
- `0` - character to be used for padding
- `2` - minimum number of characters the conversion should result in, padded with the above as necessary
- `x` - the argument is treated as an integer and presented as a hexadecimal number with lowercase letters
- `%02x%02x` - the above four repeated twice more

Answer (score 8):

You can use following function

```
function fromRGB($R, $G, $B)
{

    $R = dechex($R);
    if (strlen($R)<2)
    $R = '0'.$R;

    $G = dechex($G);
    if (strlen($G)<2)
    $G = '0'.$G;

    $B = dechex($B);
    if (strlen($B)<2)
    $B = '0'.$B;

    return '#' . $R . $G . $B;
}
```

Then, `echo fromRGB(115,25,190);` will print **#7319be**

Source: [RGB to hex colors and hex colors to RGB - PHP](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/51801-rgb-to-hex-colors-and-hex-colors-to-rgb-php/)

Answer (score 8):

You can try this simple piece of code below. You can pass the rgb code dynamically as well in the code.

```
$rgb = (123,222,132);
$rgbarr = explode(",",$rgb,3);
echo sprintf("#%02x%02x%02x", $rgbarr[0], $rgbarr[1], $rgbarr[2]);
```

This will code return like #7bde84

Comment: First line of code looks wrong, is this meant as an array or did you forget the "rgb" function name?

Comment: It's an array. Worked out really well for me, so I didn't find anything wrong with it.

Comment: Yes. Well I'm not much of an expert of PHP, but the above code did the trick for me in this case! I thought it might also help others so put it here...

Answer (score 6):

Here is a function that will accept the string version of either an `rgb` or `rgba` and return the `hex` color.

```php
    function rgb_to_hex( string $rgba ) : string {
        if ( strpos( $rgba, '#' ) === 0 ) {
            return $rgba;
        }

        preg_match( '/^rgba?[\s+]?\([\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?,[\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?,[\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?/i', $rgba, $by_color );

        return sprintf( '#%02x%02x%02x', $by_color[1], $by_color[2], $by_color[3] );
    }
```

Example:
`rgb_to_hex( 'rgba(203, 86, 153, 0.8)' );` // Returns `#cb5699`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
function rgb2html($r, $g=-1, $b=-1)
{
    if (is_array($r) && sizeof($r) == 3)
        list($r, $g, $b) = $r;

    $r = intval($r); $g = intval($g);
    $b = intval($b);

    $r = dechex($r<0?0:($r>255?255:$r));
    $g = dechex($g<0?0:($g>255?255:$g));
    $b = dechex($b<0?0:($b>255?255:$b));

    $color = (strlen($r) < 2?'0':'').$r;
    $color .= (strlen($g) < 2?'0':'').$g;
    $color .= (strlen($b) < 2?'0':'').$b;
    return '#'.$color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use external solutions, `spatie` has a package for doing exacly what you want:

https://github.com/spatie/color

```php
$rgb = Rgb::fromString('rgb(55,155,255)');

echo $rgb->red(); // 55
echo $rgb->green(); // 155
echo $rgb->blue(); // 255

echo $rgb; // rgb(55,155,255)

$rgba = $rgb->toRgba(); // `Spatie\Color\Rgba`
$rgba->alpha(); // 1
echo $rgba; // rgba(55,155,255,1)

$hex = $rgb->toHex(); // `Spatie\Color\Hex`
echo $hex; // #379bff

$hsl = $rgb->toHsl();
echo $hsl; // hsl(210,100%,100%)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the function from Mat Lipe, this changes all instances of rgb colors in a string:

```
$html = preg_replace_callback("/rgba?\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,*\s*\d*\s*\)/i", function($matches) {
    return strtoupper(sprintf("#%02x%02x%02x", $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3]));
}, $html);
```

You can remove `strtoupper` if you prefer lowercase hex.