# How to get rgb ocurrences from string and convert them to hex?

Tags: php

If you have this string in PHP:

```
$str = 'content<div style="color:rgb(0,0,0);">more content</div><div style="color: rgb(255,255,255);">more content</div>';
```

Is it possible to find the rgb occurrences and change them to hexadecimal so the new string is:

```
 $new_str = 'content<div style="color:#000000;">more content</div><div style="color: #ffffff;">more content</div>';
```

Comment: you question is two-fold, first get the color attribute first, you can use regex, then the conversion, already has solution in SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/32977705/3859027

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it: Explanation in code.

```
<?php

$input = 'content<div style="color:rgb(0,0,0);">more content</div><div style="color: rgb(255,255,255);">more content</div>';

$result = preg_replace_callback(
    // Regex that matches "rgb("#,#,#");" and gets the #,#,#
    '/rgb\((.*?)\);/',
    function($matches){
        // Explode the match (0,0,0 for example) into an array
        $colors = explode(',', $matches[1]);
        // Use sprintf for the conversion
        $match = sprintf("#%02x%02x%02x;", $colors[0], $colors[1], $colors[2]);
        return $match;
    },
    $input
);

print_r($result); //content<div style="color:#000000;">more content</div><div style="color: #ffffff;">more content</div>

?>
```

Reference: [Convert RGB to hex color values in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32962624/convert-rgb-to-hex-color-values-in-php)