# RGB to CMYK conversion

Tags: php, rgb, cmyk

Is there any way to convert HEX encoded RGB colors to CMYK in PHP? I have tried this [**PHP: HEX to CMYK**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333585/php-hex-to-cmyk) but there is a bit difference in the colors, may be the above answer converts hex to RGB then converts it to CMYK.

Comment: What do you mean by HEX? Hex is just a data representation. You can have CMYK in HEX just as well as RBG or anything else.

Comment: @Mat The OP most probably means things like `#ff00cc` (HTML hexadecimal colour codes).

Comment: YES.JamWaffles u are right :)

Comment: What are you trying to do with this hex to CMYK conversion? There might be another way to do it so that the colours are always the same. In addition, yes, the answer in the link you posted _does_ convert from hex to RGB, then CMYK.

Comment: I believe you're asking *RGB* to CMYK conversion. I've edited question. Undo the changes is this is wrong. Having said that, what is wrong with the answers to the above-mentioned question?

Comment: @SalmanBhai :: If i get RGB to CMYK or HEX CODE to CMYK Converter both will work, but if there is no color difference ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This website](http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/cmyk-rgb-and-php) goes through your problem in detail

An excerpt

> The trouble with CMYK is it's pretty rough. The technique is only
> capable reproducing some 60 or 70% of 16.7 million colours visible to
> the human eye, and which we can display on a computer screen. The RGB
> model can represent every one of these colours, and therefore every
> colour that CMYK can represent; but the converse is not true. The
> diagram on the right shows some of CMYK's closest approximations to
> some bright screen colours.

This is the reason for your "bit difference" in colors.
Hope this helps.

Comment: well, if CMYK really cannot support all colors supported by RGB, yes, it cannot be done.

Comment: -1: Your answer explains just a small part of the differences. The main reason is that all these RGB to CMYK formulas assume that color components are somehow linear. But this is far from the truth and as a result all these formulas produce colors that are only remotely similar to the original color. A serious RGB to CMYK conversion requires a color profile (a device-independent one is sufficient for more purposes).

Comment: Well it's not about not supporting the color difference comes from the conversion because rgb is formed from 3 colors and cmyk is based on 4 colors cyan yellow magenta and key. Now the thing is that in printing we do not use rgb this is used for web/monitors, we use cmyk and on the print you have other values to achieve the same colors as in rgb but they will not be the same as rgb what ever you try. i will not go more in this direction because explaining here what it goes behind cmyk profile is extensive and you need to know more about printing process.